# Problem with creating a Person Group in Cognitive Service API

Tags: python, azure-cognitive-services

I do not understand what I write to the body. What would I not wrote there, all the time generates an error when creating a personal group.

```
import http.client, urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error, base64, requests

headers = {
    # Request headers
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
}

params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
    # Request parameters
    # "personGroupId": "1",
    "name": "MyFace",
    "userData": "User-provided data attached to the person.",
    "recognitionModel": "recognition_02"
})

try:
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('XXXXX.cognitiveservices.azure.com')
    conn.request("PUT", "/face/v1.0/persongroups/{personGroupId}%s" % params, "{body", headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = response.read()
    print(data)
    conn.close()
except Excepion as e:
    print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
```

Comment: Please post your code instead of attaching photo.

Comment: What should I write in the body?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import json,http.client, urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error, base64

headers = {
    # Request headers
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '<your key here>',
}


params ={
    "name": "<your person group name here>",
    "userData": "user-provided data attached to the person group.",
    "recognitionModel": "recognition_02"
}


conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('<your endpoint name here>.api.cognitive.microsoft.com')
conn.request("PUT", "/face/v1.0/persongroups/%s" % params.get("name"), json.dumps(params), headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
data = response.read()
print(data)
print(response.getcode())
conn.close()
```

If you get a 200 code , a group has been created successfully.

Comment: Hi @MarkXado , seems you have created a person group successfully , may I know if my answer is helpful for you ? If so , pls click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in to mark it as an answer so that it will help others who has similar issue and I am glad to answer your further questions , thanks !